# Brown out reset

Tags: filesystem

Is it possible under *brownout* situation can we reset the processor(running Linux (Ubuntu/Fedora Os))which is called as *BOR(brown out reset)* ??

I want to reset the processor when it will face unexpected Power cut or low voltage while it is performing a write operation. 
Then the processor will be in hold in reset rather than try and keep running. It should then resume once the power/voltage has gone above the *brownout threshold*.

As a result due to unwanted *power cut/voltage down* it should not corrupt the linux *filesystem* or any *directory structure* along with my application.

If anyone have any suggestion please share with me.

Your suggestions will be highly appreciated...

Comment: If you frequently have a brownout situation it is probably better to have a voltage regulator or battery backup in line with the power to provide consistent power, rather than try and suspend activity when a brownout hits...

Comment: ... I should point out that this is my solution to the power issue as well - inconsistent power into my apartment could damage all the equipment I have so the items that need protected from brownout or power outages (to ensure graceful shutdown for example) all have UPSes that they connect to; the battery kicks in when the voltage drops below the threshold I set and when there is a power outage.  Gives me enough time to gracefully power down all my systems, or hibernate them in some cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible under brownout situation can we reset the processor(running Linux (Ubuntu/Fedora Os)) which is called as BOR(brown out reset) ??

No, this is not possible, and modern x86 (Intel or AMD) processors have no such feature. (Even if they had - the hard drive and all the other parts would also need to be powered so that they can finish what they were doing without data loss)

Get a UPS or a laptop with a built in battery.

Comment: If  will boot the system from a flash card in this scenario is BOR possible??

Comment: @Harsh No, you may still loose data if the power is cut.

Comment: @Harsh Basically what you want cannot be achieved.  It's not technologically possible.  Get a UPS or a laptop with a battery if brownouts are an issue